# How to get user information for logged in user SpringSecurity + AngularJS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, angularjs

Currently I am using the following to log users into my application. However I would like to use an angular function to actually perform the login. To do this I would like to create a rest web service to authenticate, however all the examples I see on SO use User which I thought was Depreciated. I would also like the service to return information about the user.

The short of what I am asking is how can I change the MyUserDetailsService to be used as a restful service for logging in, or how can I create a service that I can use for logging in that will return the user object after logging in.

```
<form class="navbar-form" action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
   <input class="span2" name="j_username"  type="text" placeholder="Email">
   <input class="span2" name="j_password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log in"/>
</form>
```

This is my authenticationManager

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="MyUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here is the user details service I am currently using for login.

```
@Service("MyUserDetailsService")
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);

    private UserManager userManager;

    @Autowired
    public MyUserDetailsService(UserManager userManager) {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        if ((email == null) || email.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email is null or empty");
        }
        logger.debug("Checking users with email: " + email);

        Users users = userManager.findByEmail(email);

        if (users == null) {
            String errorMsg = "User with email: " + email + " could not be found";
            logger.debug(errorMsg);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(errorMsg);
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = toGrantedAuthorities(users.getRoleNames());
        String password = users.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = users.isEnabled();
        boolean userNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean userNonLocked = true;

        return new User(email, password, enabled, userNonExpired, userNonLocked, credentialsNonExpired, grantedAuthorities);
    }

    public static Collection<GrantedAuthority> toGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> result = newArrayList();

        for (String role : roles) {
            result.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: [User](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java) isn't deprecated. It's not really clear what you are asking apart from that. Do you have a problem with the code you have posted?

Comment: Luke,  I updated the question so hopefully that helps. basically I want to either update the MyUserDetailsService so that I can use it as a rest service consumed by AngularJS, with the additional goal for the MyUserDetailsService to return a user object to be used throughout the application.

Comment: You can expose it using a basic MVC controller, but that might allow anyone to read user account details, including passwords over the web. Can you expand a bit what you're trying to achieve? Authentication should generally take place on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: I want the authentication to take place on the server, however after a user is authenticated I would like some of their info to be sent back to the browser so I can use it.  Example being their username, so I can have welcome message, their settings etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some [JSTL tags for Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) you can use on the View to do some things.  If JSTL is not an option, for whatever reason(s), you can do something like this:

```
${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal.yourCustomProperty}
```

Also, you could get the Principal in your Controller and set it on the Model.

Comment: while not exactly what I had in mind this does do what I was hoping to do.  Thank you very much!